# Check if the innerText of a selector includes a substring

Tags: javascript, string, substring, testcafe, assertion

I need to test whether the innerText of a element contains a substring using testcafe, but I'm not able to figure out the right way to do that.

```
Selector('.displayed-result').innerText = '12 results'
Selector('user-details').count = 12
```

This is what I've tried -

```
await t.expect(Selector('.displayed-result').innerText).contains(`${Selector('user-details').count);
```

What is the correct way to check this as contains doesn't return the right result?

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe doesn't evaluate expressions in [assertion methods](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/assertion-api.html).

You need to rewrite your code as follows:

```js
const userDetailCount = await Selector('user-details').count;

await t.expect(Selector('.displayed-result').innerText).contains(userDetailCount.toString()));
```